# Updating multiple id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm update few text in a page using `<SPAN ID="idName">` based on dropdown selection  ID, but only the first element ID changes. Using different ID's work but was hoping there is an easier solution. I am using twitter-bootstrap-3 for my dropdown menu.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li class="dropdown menu-btn">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> <span id="SelectName"></span><b     class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul id="myCitylist" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">San Jose</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Silicon Valley</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">New York City</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Paris</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Silicon Valley</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Tokyo</a> </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>

Now we'll talk about <span id="SelectName"></span>
```

and javascript

```
 document.getElementById("SelectName").innerHTML = "San Francisco";

 $('#myCitylist li').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("SelectName").innerHTML = $(this).text();

 });

 document.getElementById("SelectName").innerHTML = "San Francisco";
```

Here's the code : http://jsfiddle.net/ub1g7fw6/

Comment: "id" attributes must be unique on the page.

Comment: kind of got that with my experimentation, but hoping there would be a simpler solution then just using bunch of different ID's all over the place.

Comment: @VivekKumar  : use classes eg- <div class="myClass"></div>

Comment: attach a dummy class and use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id`'s can only be used once on the page. You can do this by using a `class` instead:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="dropdown menu-btn">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> 
         <span class="update">San Francisco</span><b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul id="myCitylist" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">San Jose</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Silicon Valley</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">New York City</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Paris</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Silicon Valley</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Tokyo</a> </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div>Now we'll talk about <span class="update">San Francisco</span></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', "li", function(){
  var optionChosen = $(this).text();
  $(this).closest("ul.nav.nav-pills").find("span.update").text(optionChosen).end().next().find("span.update").text(optionChosen);  
 });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ub1g7fw6/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for classes in this instance, although a combination of classes and ID's can make life a lot easier. For example you might wish to style all of your list items to have a large font size (classes used here) but require javascript functionality on only one of them (ID's used here).

**The following is intended to be an educational example.**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li class="dropdown menu-btn">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> <span id="SelectName"></span><b     class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul id="myCitylist" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="large-text" id="red-hover"> <a href="#">San Jose</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Silicon Valley</a> </li>
        <li class="large-text"> <a href="#">New York City</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Paris</a> </li>
        <li class="large-text"> <a href="#">Silicon Valley</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Tokyo</a> </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.large-text
{
    font-size: larger;
}
```

**JQuery (Javascript)**

```
$("#red-hover").on({
    mouseenter: function () 
    {
        $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
    },
    mouseleave: function () 
    {
        $( this ).css( "color", "black" );
    }
});

Now we'll talk about <span id="SelectName"></span>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zp87p6a4/)

That being said the same logic also works for javascript i.e. you could set your script to target all elements with the class provided e.g. set your red-hover ID to be a class by converting the # prefix to a . prefix in javascript/css and of course setting the class to be "red-hover" and removing the reference to the "red-hover" id in your HTML.